# how to use mirrored text in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

code sample

```
type here
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
   QPainter chartPainter;
   QPointF qChart;
   QFont font;

   chartPainter.begin(this);
   qChart = QPointF(100, 100); // x postion, y position

    chartPainter.drawText(qChart, "A", 0, 0);
}
```

How can I display the letter "A" in Qt as mirrored text?
How to apply mirrored text to all text, not just "A"?

QImage has a function called mirrored that can be applied. However, the method using QPainter is not found even after searching.

Is there a way that can be implemented with QPainter or some other way?

Comment: Are you mirroring letters, words or sentences?  The letter `'A'` is symmetrical.  Try using another letter like `E` or `C`.  Are you talking vertical mirroring like printing upside-down?

Comment: I wonder if this could be done by calling `QPainter::setTransform()` with a `QTransform` object that has its horizontal-scaling factor set to -1.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the `Qt::TextDirection` property of a `QPainter` object.

Add these to your code:

```
painter.setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
painter.drawText(rect, Qt::AlignRight, tr("Text goes here"));
```

Comment: void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QPainter p(this);
    QPointF qChart;
    QRect rect(100, 100, width(), height());

    p.setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
    p.drawText(rect, Qt::AlignRight, tr("hi"));
} // I did as you suggested, but the text output is the same. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: This has impact only on letters which do not have associated text direction. For example digits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a QImage and draw on it. You draw over the image in the Painter.
[image]

`.h`

```
............
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
private:
    void drawText(const QString &text);
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QImage image;
    bool drawing;
...........
```

`.cpp`

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    image = QImage(size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    drawing = true; // for updating once

}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    image = image.mirrored(true, false);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(rect(), QGradient(QGradient::SaintPetersburg));
    painter.drawImage(rect(), image);

    if(drawing)
        drawText("Mirrored");
}

void Widget::drawText(const QString &text)
{
    QPainter painter(&image);

    // set a font
    QFont font = painter.font();
    font.setFamily("Helvetica");
    font.setPixelSize(20);
    painter.setFont(font);

    // metrics for centerPos and size
    QFontMetrics metrics(painter.fontMetrics());

    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    // keep it in the middle if possible (is only for the optics. you don't have to do it like that)
    painter.drawText((width()/2) -(metrics.horizontalAdvance(text))-10,
                     (height()/2) - (metrics.height()),
                     metrics.horizontalAdvance(text),
                     metrics.height(),
                     0,
                     text);
    update();
    drawing = false;
}
```

Just a small note: if you draw directly in the painter, the picture will flicker. you can work around it by calling the image directly in the constructor.

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    image = QImage(size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    //image.fill(Qt::white);
    //drawing = true; // update once
    drawText("Mirrored");
    image = image.mirrored(true, false);
}
.........

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(rect(), QGradient(QGradient::SaintPetersburg));
    painter.drawImage(rect(), image);
}

........
```